# Did I just make a buffer overflow?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, buffer-overflow

I was learning loops for PHP and as I did the FOR loop it seems I messed up. 
Basically, well this happened:

```
    for($i = 2; $i++; $i < 26) {
   print $i;
  }
```

I fixed it by adding $i++ last. But my question is: Was this a buffer overflow?
It exceeded number 10000

Answer (score 8):

No, it is simply an *infinite loop*. There's nothing adding memory to anything, so there's nothing to overflow. It will simply never stop running, that's all.

Comment: Why infinite? See my comment above.

Comment: @John Integers overflow into floats, so your theory doesn't hold. http://3v4l.org/ckIup

Answer (score 3):

Wrong way round:

```
for($i = 2; $i < 26; $i++) {
   print $i;
}
```

PHP `for loop` works like this:

```
for(<initialization>; <condition>; <iteration>) {

}
```

You can put anything inside these fields, however to make it work correctly, you need to understand what PHP is doing with them.

$i = 2; That is the initialization, you are preparing the `incremental variable`.

$i < 26; That is the condition, `while $i is less than 26`

$i++; The iteration. `after each turn of the loop, add` to $i`.

When $i equals 25 in this case, the loop will end.

Answer (score 2):

It should be...

```
for($i = 2;  $i < 26; $i++) {
  print $i;
}
```

See manual http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 1):

I think that it was an endless loop. Whatever you place on the second position indicates the condition until the loop is going to continue iterating. As you'll always be able to increase $i by one, the condition is always true thus you end up iterating forever.